# jQuery selector not working as I expected(multiple :not selector not working?)

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'd like to close my lightbox when the red zone is clicked:
[image]
http://naokonishimura.com/witoart/2d/

And the HTML for this light box goes like this:

```
<div id="#lightbox" style="display:block;">
<div class="contents_lb">
    <div class="img_box" style="margin-top: 74.5px; width: 398px; height: 563px;">
        <a class="close" href="#" style="left: calc(50% + 159px);"></a>
        <a class="full" href="#" style="left: calc(50% + 159px); top: 523px;"></a>
        <div class="img_wrap" style="width: 398px; left: calc(50% - 199px);">
            <img class="lightbox" alt="Wito RenderA3 TEISHITSUblue 1000p wide" src="http://naokonishimura.com/witoart/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/Wito-RenderA3-TEISHITSUblue-1000p-wide.png" style="opacity: 100; height: 596px;">
            <div class="desc">
                <h2>
                    Wito RenderA3 TEISHITSUblue 1000p wide
                </h2>
                <p></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But I'm confused with how I can select this area. I wrote this JQuery code to close the lightbox

```
jQuery("#lightbox.close,#lightbox:not(.contents_lb):not(.img_box):not(.img_wrap):not(.img_wrap img):not(.img_wrap .desc)").click(function(){
                jQuery("#lightbox").remove();
            });
```

But the lightbox closes when anywhere on #lightbox is clicked. How can I select the area on #lightbox EXCEPT on the pic? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Events bubble up the DOM unless cancelled. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$("#lightbox:not(.myClass)") accepts all divs with id lightbox that don't have class "myClass", which of course is your lightbox.

Try something like this:

```
jQuery("#lightbox").on("click", function(e) {
    if(e.target === this || $(e.target).is(".close")) {
        jQuery("#lightbox").remove();
    }
});
```

event.target tells you where the original click came from. By checking that it isn't from a lower level div, you can ignore clicks that didn't come from the red area.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like

```
jQuery("#lightbox").click(function (e) {
    if (jQuery(e.target).closest('.img_wrap').length) {
        return;
    }
    jQuery("#lightbox").remove();
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ms50b1h7/)

Answer (score 0):

As Matt Ball said in his comment, events bubble up unless cancelled. Try this:

```
jQuery("#lightbox.close,#lightbox:not(.contents_lb):not(.img_box):not(.img_wrap):not(.img_wrap img):not(.img_wrap .desc)").click(function(e){
                e.stopPropagation();
                jQuery("#lightbox").remove();
            });
```

http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/